# Sudden slowness in System.arraycopy in Tablet

Tags: java, arrays, performance, memory, slowdown

I have a Intel(R) Atom(TM) x5-Z8300 CPU@GHz Tablet. The java application contains few threads, queues, arraycopy, etc to process data frames and display in a table. The tablet was working fine. Last few weeks we observed slowness in the tablet, on debugging found that each System.arraycopy consumes around 20 milliseconds on an average. 
CPU % = 30
Memory% = 70
We tried System.arraycopy in a standalone java exe and ran in the tablet, it took around 420 milliseconds to copy an array of 1000 length 100 iterations (i.e) 100 x System.arraycopy(1000). Normal system consumes 72 milliseconds.

Is there any way to identify slowness in the java application or any suggestions to corner the problem.

Comment: What kind of JVM runs on a Intel(R) Atom(TM) x5-Z8300 CPU@GHz Tablet?

Comment: JVM details: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM,
C:\\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_101,
Oracle Corporation,
1.8.0_101,
Oracle Corporation,
32 bit

Comment: How did you find that arraycopy takes 20 ms? That's an awfully long time. What measurement method did you use?

Comment: Using System.nanotime() api.